# Multimeter effects on current flow

Tags: current-measurement, multimeter

I am trying to measure the current flows over time of a Particle Argon from the initial boot, through normal processing then going into deep sleep mode. My code runs great on its own and does exactly what I want, repeatedly when I wire things up like in Scenario A.  However, Scenario B I am using a Siglent multimeter to do the current measurements and the Argon fails after the initial power on, resets, and trys again.  This process repeats indefinitely.  The power amp is set to deliver a max of 1A which is well beyond what the Argon would pull right at power up.

Is my multimeter "faulty" or is there something I am not considering in my setup to make this measurement successfully?  I realize the Siglent SDM3055 is not the highest end multimeter, but surely it is made well enough to do this type of test?  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Note same power supply and setting used in both scenarios.

[image]

Comment: try measuring current on the high side of the supply so you have a direct ground connection.

Comment: Kevin - Hi, There's nothing wrong with your (very clear) question, but FYI it is effectively a duplicate of [this previous one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/546569/why-is-my-multimeter-stopping-device-from-booting-when-measuring-current) where measuring current caused the same reboot loop behavior as you are seeing, for the same reason. So you will find useful info there, as well as in the answer you received here. Searching for "burden voltage" will find some other related questions. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @samgibson.  I was reading through that question now.  Also good information.  The shorting of the meter through power up and then removing to put the meter in the loop sounds promising and I will try that.

Answer (score 2):

Multimeters measure current by measuring the voltage across a series resistor. This voltage drop is called the burden voltage and is effectively subtracted from your power supply.

Lower current ranges use a higher value resistor for the measurement.

I would not use auto-ranging and set the DC current range to its highest setting -- i.e. 10A, and see if that works.

For measuring very small currents while keeping the burden voltage down there are amplifiers available such as the Current Ranger, BattLab-One or µCurrent, ...

- Current Ranger - https://lowpowerlab.com/guide/currentranger/
- BattLab-One - https://bluebird-labs.com/
- uCurrent - https://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/
- Nordic Power Profiler Kit II - https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/Power-Profiler-Kit-2
- Otii - https://www.qoitech.com/otii/
- Joulescope - https://www.joulescope.com/products/joulescope-precision-dc-energy-analyzer

Comment: Thank you @ErikR. I will try that out right now.

Comment: I set the range to the lowest of 200uA but unfortunately, the Siglent Power Supply appears to be limited to a max of 3.3A.  At that setting, it is still resetting right after each power-up.  I guess I will need to go purchase the ucurrent. :-)

Comment: Discontinued. Was looking for one last week.

Comment: I updated the answer with a couple of other products.

Comment: Another lab that I work in has a Rigol multimeter.  I have definitely seen measurements displayed on it for example 0.121 uA.  I assumed this was essentially 121 nano-amps but after reading the specs from bluebirds lab that equipment only goes down to 10uA.  Clearly I need to do my homework and watch these videos on EEVBlog but am I interpreting the display reading incorrectly on the Rigol?

Comment: Perhaps, but it could also be due to noise. Just checked my Fluke 8845 and it shows 100nA when shorting the current inputs.